# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () using MongoDB atlas react site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Looking for trouble shooting ideas.

React app works perfectly on my local host but after being deployed it gives me the above error of

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
```

when I go to create a user, and yes I have all ips white listed in atlas. All I could think is that its an issue with my API, but wouldnt it have not worked locally if that was the case?

site in question - https://badbank3.herokuapp.com/#/CreateAccount/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it works perfectly fine, though you get a 400 from firebase if :

- email is badly formatted ex: space at the begining or like test@gmail
- you have a password shorter than 6 chars
- you have no name

Comment: oh wow and yeah I see your test in the database, weird, on my machine it just stalls

Comment: how are you running your application in your local environment ? I think you struggle calling your database from your local env, but the deployed app seems to work fine

are you sure you don't have any error in the console ? Also, if you are testing your deployed app, have you tried from another browser or some private nav ?